# return array to coder.ceval

Tags: c, matlab, code-generation

I need to call a c-function from matlab using `y=coder.ceval()` and return a string from the function. However the  `coder.ceval()` function only allows me to return a scalar value. String is however an array of char, and thus cannot be returned. The code in matlab function looks like:

```
function y = abc(param)

 y = '';

 if strcmp(coder.target,'rtw'),

  y=coder.ceval('c-function',param);

 end

end
```

Is there any solution or workaround for it?

Looking forward for some help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

EDITING

This is a workaround and you should use it at your own risk! ;)
I mean if it is really your last option.

As you do not specify the kind of string I assume for simplicity that it is composed only by uppercase letters (AABBBCC).
Uppercase letters are represented as decimal numbers by 2 digits (A = 65, Z = 90, man ascii).

This method comprises two steps:
1) In your function that you call via coder.ceval you should build a scalar value from the string you want to return. 2) You have to rebuild the string from the scalar value.

The following code illustrates by a simple example how to carry out the two steps. Keep in mind that is only an example and you have to work on it. Let's suppose for example that you need to return the string "ABC" then you can return the scalar "656667" which is composed by the three 2-digits numbers: 65=A, 66=B, 67=C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int i, len, n;

    // First convert a string in a scalar value
    char str[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', '\0'};

    printf("str = %s\n", str);
    len = strlen(str);


    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        n = str[i] + i*100;
    }
    printf("n = %d\n", n);


    // You return a scalar that is composed by 65,66,67 ---> A,B,C
    int y = 656667;

    char num[100];
    char letter[3];

    // convert the number in a string    
    snprintf(num, 100, "%d", y);
    printf("num = %s\n", num);
    len = strlen(num);
    printf("num len = %d\n", len);
    // here we assume that the number of digits id even only ascii letters
    if ((len%2) != 0) exit(1);

    // Now we have to store the number of two digits as numbers and
    // then convert the to char and finally append tehm to a string
    int *ni = malloc((len/2)*sizeof(int));
    char *string = malloc(len + 1);

    // Here I use a lot of intermediate steps to make it clear
    char c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len/2; i+=1) {
        snprintf(letter, 3, "%c%c", num[2*i], num[2*i+1]);
        ni[i] = atoi(letter);
        c = (char)ni[i];
        printf("letter %d = %s, x = %d, c = %c\n", i, letter, ni[i], c);
        string[i] = c;
        printf("string[%d] = %c\n", i, string[i]);
    }

    // print the final string
    string[len] = '\0';
    printf("string = %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Lowercase letters starts at 97 but then become 3 digits, however by using some "special number" of 2 digits one can even decide to read 2 digits at the beginning of the string and 3 digits after the "special number".

Ok, I am not sure that this will help but, at least,  I hope you find it interesting.